# Some Japanese texts display wrong on safari mobile

Tags: ios, css, safari

i'm making a website for a Japanese company. Everything is ok except one: some (not all) Japanese text display wrong (look like a square) on Safari on IPhone while other web browsers and devices display exactly including Ipad. Here are these characters: "・" , "〜".

My header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Don't want to show</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="share/css/common.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="share/css/base.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="share/css/top.css"/>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>
```

My font: font-family: Meiryo;

Answer (score 0):

your issue is that you never defined the html language in the html tag. Try  `<html lang="ja" class="no-js">`